# ¿como puedo hacer con java script que al momento de que en el documento aparezca un id ejecute una función?

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap

cabe resaltar que estoy usando Bootstrap.
codigo HTML ejemplo:
tengo un `input`.

```
<input class="form-control form-control-lg" list="datalistUsername" type="text" id="username" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre de Usuario" onkeydown="Myfuncion()" autofocus />
<datalist id="datalistUsername">
</datalist>
```

Codigo Java Script:

```
let Result;
let Username;

window.onload = function(){

Result= document.getElementById("datalistUsername")
Username= document.getElementById("username")

function Myfuncion(){

let template = ""

template+=`<option id="id_nuevo" value="${Username.value}">`

Result.innerHTML = template

}

}
```

me explico al principio cuando cargo el documento claramente `<option id="id_nuevo" value="${Username.value}">` no esta, quiero saber que cuando el `id_nuevo` aparezca en el documento ejecute otra función x. si se puede hacer ?

Answer (score 1):

En tu caso específico, puedes añadir un callback como return de Myfuncion ya que ahí obtienes el comportamiento que buscas: función que se ejecute después que el id aparezca.

Otras opciones en función de tu experiencia podría ser crear un setInterval que verifique si el elemento existe o más técnico, utilizar el MutationObserver.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Espero te sirva, saludos!